# Difficulty with map of map deletion

Tags: c++

How do you delete the first element of the inner map of a map of a map?

I've tried doing something like

```
my_map[here].erase(my_map[here].begin())
```

but I'm getting unexpected results.  Any suggestions or resources would be great.

Comment: Does the standard state that a map<> should provide any guarantee of ordering. I guess what I'm saying is "how do you know that the element returned by map.begin() is the element you want to delete anyway?"

Comment: I use a comparison class to ensure that the beginning is always the element I want to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does my_map[here] actually exist?

You may want to find it, i.e.

```
if((auto it = my_map.find(here)) != my_map.end()) {
  it->erase(it->begin());

}
```

If my_map[here] didn't exist when you tried to access it, a new element will be created there:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/

```
If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the container size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the element is constructed using its default constructor).
```

To prevent this, you can use the `find` function as I have indicated above.
`find` searches for the element with the specified key. If it finds something, it will return the iterator to that element. Otherwise, it will return `my_map.end()`, which is NOT the last element but a special iterator signifying the end of the structure.

Comment: @BobJohn: Using `my_map[here]` will create a new element with the key `here` if one doesn't already exist. `my_map.find()` will return `my_map.end()` if the element doesn't exist.

Comment: If my_map[here] doesn't actually exist at the time you try to access it, a new element will get created:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/


`If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the container size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the element is constructed using its default constructor).`

Comment: This solution doesn't work.  I'm still getting unexpected results (that is, my program completely breaks).

Comment: Alright ... in what way does it break? Do you get a seg fault?

Comment: Never mind.  I was doing something foolish.  Thanks for your help.